# What to check for IIS Performance Monitoring

Tags: iis, performance-monitoring

I'm trying to discover why an internet server is running on the slow side.

One thing that the site does is to use an external data source, and we know those queries are slow, but these long queries also seem to affect the site in general.

It seems to me that it could be that maybe IIS is having to queue up requests or something, or perhaps memory is a problem.

Could anyone suggest a good set of measurements to look at to see where the problem might be?